# Require without keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some code that goes like this:

```js
function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}

function bar() {
  return 'foo';
}

var hello = 'world';
var world = 'hello';
```

I want to use these functions and variables in a different file. I know I can use `module.exports = {foo, bar, hello, world}` and then require `const foofile = require('./foofile.js')`in a different file, but that makes me use them like `foofile.foo()`. Is there and way I can avoid this so I just have to type `foo()` in the other file?

### Edit:

I see the 2 answers but when I test the code everything I require is undefined. I might  as well just put it here, since it isn't that long anyway.

```js
// vars.js (in root folder)
const sleep = require('./functions/sleep');
const scenarios = require('./scenarios.json')
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {sleep, scenarios, fs, Discord, client}
// sleep.js (in subfolder functions)
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
module.exports = sleep;
//startTheGame.js (in subfolder functions)

const {sleep, scenarios, fs, Discord, client} = require('../vars')
async function startTheGame(channel) {
    await sleep(1500);
    const embed = Discord.MessageEmbed();
}
module.exports = startTheGame;
```

It's returning `sleep is not a function` and when I delete `await sleep(1500);` it returns `cannot read property MessageEmbed of undefined`.

I know this is becoming pretty long, and it might be because of a simple slip-up by me, but if anyone could help me, that would be great. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import them using object destructuring like this:

```
const {foo, bar, hello, world} = require('./foofile.js');
```

Then, `foo`, `bar`, `hello` and `world` will be top level variables in your module and you can just refer to them directly as in `foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can destruct the content required from the module, therefore you can avoid the mentioned syntax of `foofile.foo()`.

Consider the module you described and a `index.js` which is requiring it using the destructuring syntax.

```
// mymodule.js
function foo() {
  return "bar";
}

function bar() {
  return "foo";
}

// Consider using const and let instead of var
const hello = "world";
const world = "hello";

module.exports = { foo, bar, hello, world };
```

```js
// index.js
const { foo, bar, hello, world } = require('./mymodule');

console.log(foo()); // "bar"
console.log(bar()); // "foo"
console.log(hello); // "world"
console.log(world); // "hello"
```